# Surface from level curves of unkown levels in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, contour

I want to obtain a n*m matrix with a approximated "height" at each discrete point. The input is a picture (see link below) of the contours from a map, each contourline represents an 5m increase or decrease of the height.

My thoughts:

- I imported the picture as a logical png to a matrix called `A` which means that every contourline in the matrix is a connected strip of '1's and everything else is just 0.
- My initial thought was to just start in the upper left corner of the matrix, set that height to zero, declare a new matrix 'height' and start with figuring out `height(:,1)` by adding 5 meters each time we meet a '1' in the `A` matrix. Knowing the whole first colonn I now for each row start from the left and add 5 m each time we meet a '1'.
- I quickly realized however that this wouldn't work since there is no way for the algorithm to understand whether it should add or subtract height, i.e if we are running uphill or downhill.
- If I somehow could approximate the gradient from the intensity of contourlines that would be great even though it would always be possible for a uphill to be a downhill and vice versa but then I could manually decide which is true of these two cases.

Picture: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRkiY.jpg]

Comment: Before your thoughts, your data! Do you hae just an image? Or do you have the curves in some format? what format?

Comment: Input data is just an image which represents the level curves of some unkown surface which I want to approximate given that I know the height difference between each level curve.

Comment: What is the desired output format? Does it need to be a meshgrid, or can it be e.g. a triangle mesh?

Comment: Also, is that your original image, a jpg? or do you haeve a png? because jpg has image artifacts

Comment: I think I would prefer a standard meshgrid altough any meshgrid would be a step forward for me. A meshgrid with the approximated height at each point is my desired output.

Comment: My original image is a png but I can get it in any desired picture format.

Comment: You linked a JPG, not a PNG. PNG>>JPG!

Comment: There is a problem with your images: There is no way to know if a line is higher or lower altitude, you just need to make a guess every time, thus there are thousands of possible solutions

Answer (score 2):

**WORK IN PROGRESS**

```
%% Read and binarize the image
I=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRkiY.jpg'); 
I=rgb2gray(I);
I=I>graythresh(I)*255;

%% Get skeleton, i.e. the lines!
sk=bwmorph(~I,'skel',Inf);

%% lines are too thin, dilate them
dilated=~imdilate(sk, strel('disk', 2, 4));

%% label the image!
test=bwlabel(dilated,8);

imshow(test,[]); colormap(plasma); % use colormap parula if you prefer.
```

[image]

Missing: label each adjacent area with a number +1 (or -1) its neighbours (No idea how to do this)

Missing: Interpolate flat areas. This should be doable once the altitudes are known. One can set the pixels in the skeleton image to the altitudes and interpolate the rest using `griddata`, which will be slow, but still doable.

---

Disclaimer: not full answer yet, feel free to edit or reuse the code in this answer to further it!

Comment: This was pretty much what I was looking for as a first step, thanks! I realize that it is impossible, as you say, to tell wheter a line is higher or lower than the previous one. When the lines are closed you can maybe make som assumptions that every line represents an increase in altitude because that is usually the case. However, for lines that are not closed it is harder to make assumptions. Maybe it is impossible to retrieve a good height surface given just a picture of the contours even under some ass umptions.

Comment: @Signe66 definetly the "missing" steps that I say are doable, but this is an under-determined problem, only solvable by assumptions, that as you say, may not really hold.